# Is a biplane without dihedral more stable than a low wing monoplane without dihedral?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, general-aviation

I was wondering if a biplane's top mounted wing created the same stability effect as that of a high wing airplane?
Also, would the unstable effects of the low wing cancel the stability provided by the high wing and condition the biplane to behave like a mid wing airplane? If yes, is it one of the reasons why manufacturers make the top wing longer or is it just extra length provided to generate more lift and replace that lost due to wing interference?
This questions have been bugging me for some time now. 
Someone pls clarify me.
Maybe I missed something...

Comment: What makes you think that a high wing provides stability?

Comment: interesting question

Comment: I just thought it did.

Answer (score 1):

Narrow answer: Yes, it is.

But no aircraft designer in his right mind would build an unswept low wing aircraft without dihedral. So this question is misleading.

Please look [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12099/why-do-low-wing-aircraft-have-higher-dihedral-than-high-wing-aircraft/12101#12101) why low wing aircraft need more dihedral.

Please read [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26396/why-are-high-wing-aircraft-more-stable) why a low wing aircraft is just as stable as a high wing aircraft. The high wing does not entail more stability!

Comment: Okay. That's new. I always thought a high wing produced a self correcting!

Comment: Doesn't a high wing airplane stabilize it self in the roll axis after the pilot centers the stick(without using opposite aileron)? I learnt that the c.g is below the wing and this tends to prevent or dampen roll of the airplane.

Comment: Okay. I think I get it. Thanks a lot. That was very helpful.    One more mystery about biplanes; why don't they ever come with a T-tail...now I haven't seen all the biplanes in the world...so maybe it exists. If it does pls share a link or an image. I'm yet to see a biplane with a T-tail or a cruciform tail(as long as the tail is higher than the top wing of the biplane.

Comment: @user16656: No. Please read the linked answer, and maybe [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26574/what-is-the-keel-effect/26588?s=1|0.2270#26588), too.